# Html5 video is not displaying in internet explorer 11.0.15 browser update only audio is playing

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Demo video player</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<h2> video Player demo</h2>
<video id="MY_VIDEO_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="" data-setup="{}">
  <source src="files/11.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
</body> 
</html>
```

this works fine in all browser as well IE 8-10 and 11(11.0.11 updates) but Please suggest me what is the issue with IE-11.0.15 browser

Comment: I'm getting this error: The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported. and I'm using Google Crome. Check video file availability.

Comment: Ya I have H264 Codec formatted video it's working fine with all browsers even in IE 9 to 11 .. but only in ie -11.0.15 it is not working. Just audio is playing.

Comment: you can use any video converter to convert the video to mp4 format along with that you need to make that video as h264 format then only u could able  see it in browser.